# ASP.net calling Salesforce webservice to upload attachment

Tags: webservices, attachment, .net, fileupload

i have a website created using ASP.net and i would like to allow people to upload files from the website and i want those files is then store in Salesforce.

I am not good in webservice but i think the only way is to call Salesforce webservice API to pass the file right?

Can anyone give me some guidance how to do it? I have to convert the file into base64? and then call Salesforce webservice? Do i need to pass my salesforce credential?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, not quite a .NET guy. But I had written a post about accessing RESET services for attachments from Javascript. Will help a bit, hopefully.

https://crmcog.com/retrieve-sfdc-attachments-using-rest/